# How to find position of point that is x unit distant from AB line segment and y unit distant from BC line segment?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

[image: Representation image]

I am trying to calculate coordinates of point P, which is x units distant from AB line segment and y units distant from BC line segment.

Edit:
I am trying to write code for general solution. 
As parameters, I have three points (coordinates) A, B and C and also two values for distance x and y.

Comment: Are you familiar with the formula that expresses distance between line and a point?

Comment: @Alistair yes I am.  I am trying to write the code for general solution for given parameters.

Comment: Ok. Are these parameters coordinates of three points or equations of two lines?

Comment: I have three points (coordinates) A, B and C and also two values for distance x and y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Without loss of generality we can assume that $B$ is the origin and $C$ is a point on the $x$ axis. Changing a bit your notation, let $P=(x_P,\pm b)$ where $|b|$ is the distance from $BC$ (your $y$).  If we have $A=(x_A,y_A)$ than the line $BA=r$ has equation $ y_Ax-x_Ay=0$.

The distance $a$ of $P$ from this line $r$ is:
$$
\overline{Pr}=\frac{|y_Ax_P\mp x_Ab|}{\sqrt{x_A^2+y_A^2}}=a
$$
 Solving this equations you can find all points $x_P$.

---

If all the points $A,B,C$ are given in some coordinate system, then you have to perform a change of coordinates, that, in general, is given by a translation and a rotation. Or you can find the equations of the two lines:
$$
a_1x+b_1y+c_1=0 \qquad a_2x+b_2y+c_2=0
$$

and solve the system of the two equation for the distances of the point $P$ from these two lines.

Comment: Point C is also parameterize and there is no guarantee it will be on the x axis.

Answer (score 1):

We can, without loss of generality, assume a coordinate system with origin at B and x-axis along line BC.  Then line AB can be written as y= mx.

Since I am using an xy-coordinate system, I am going to call the distance to the given point, from line AB, "p" rather than "x" and the distance to line BC "q" rather than "y".

Let the given point have coordinates, in this coordinate system, $(x_0, y_0)$.  Then we must have $y_0= q$.  The distance from (x0, y0) to line AB is $\frac{|mx0- y0|}{\sqrt{m^2+ 1}}= p$.

Solve those two equations for $x_0$ and $y_0$.

Comment: Point C is also parameterize and there is no guarantee it will be on the x axis.

Comment: I have corrected my answer and added something. I think that the simpler way is to change the coordinates...

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to do this.

You could set up an equation for the distance from an arbitrary point $(u,v)$ to the extended line $AB$, and
another equation for the distance from an arbitrary point $(u,v)$ to the extended line $BC$.
(I can't write the coordinates of the point as $(x,y)$ since you already
used those symbols to mean something else.)
Solve these simultaneous equations for $u$ and $v$.
You will get four solutions, but three of them are either on the 
wrong side of $AB$ or the wrong side of $BC$ so you reject them.

Another way, find the equation of 
a line parallel to $AB$
but at distance $x$ from $AB$, on the same side of $AB$ as $C$ is, 
and the equation of another line parallel to $BC$
but at distance $y$ from $BC$, on the same side of $BC$ as $A$ is.
Find the intersection point of those two lines by solving these
equations simultaneously.

Either of these methods requires some work.
You might do just as well to use Emilio Novati's method, including
the change of coordinates.

Comment: Actually I implemented second idea of yours, however for some parameters, new parallel line segments won't intersect.

Comment: If $A, B, C$ are collinear and $x \neq y$ then there cannot be a solution by any method. Otherwise there should be one.

Comment: no they are never linear, I guess my problem is I am using parallel line segments while you suggested using lines.

Comment: You do need to be careful how you define "distance". Just shifting the line "up" by $x$ units is not right unless $AB$ is horizontal; you want to move $x$ units perpendicular to $AB$. But yes, it is easier if you use the equation for the whole line rather than limiting to a segment. "On the same side of $AB$ as C" is how the exact choice of segments figures into the solution.